# What is the BEST way to iterate through Hashtable entries WITHOUT the java.lang.Map APIs?

Tags: java, blackberry, hashtable

I am working on a BlackBerry j2me Java implementation that does not have the Collections API.  So there is no `entrySet()` method or `Map.Entry` class.  The only available methods to iterate through the mappings of a `Hashtable` are the `elements()` and `keys()` methods.

Can I expect `elements()` and `keys()` to return the same number of mappings, in the same order?  If so, I can do the following:

```
Enumeration keys = table.keys();
Enumeration elements = table.elements();
String key, value;
while(keys.hasMoreElements()) {
    key = keys.nextElement();
    value = elements.nextElement();
}
```

I would think this is the case, but the docs don't say for sure.  If I can't make this assumption, then I will have to iterate through the keys only:

```
Enumeration keys = table.keys();
String key, value;
while(keys.hasMoreElements()) {
    key = keys.nextElement();
    // Less efficient b/c I have to do a lookup every time.
    value = table.get(key);
}
```

**Edit:** You can assume only one thread has access to the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are guaranteed to return the same *number* of items. And in Sun's implementation, keys and values are returned in the same order. (In fact, under the covers, the same class serves to iterate over keys, values or Map.Entry objects.) Indeed, it's hard to imagine getting the values in some way other than by iterating over the buckets.

However, the language specification doesn't say they have to be in the same order, so if you make that assumption, you will hinder portability and possibly introduce hard-to-find bugs later on. I think it was the algorithms expert Donald Knuth who said, "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil." Unless that particular part of the code is a huge bottleneck, I recommend you do the lookup for each key.

Comment: Agreed, for the most part.  But since this is a BlackBerry-only application and the implementation is well-established, portability and forward-compatibility are less of a concern.  And I'm usually a fan of the old Knuth quote, but people do use it as an excuse to be ignorant.  If I know one way is better, then there's no reason I shouldn't do it the right way the first time around.  I found another place in our code base where we rely on this assumption, and it works, so I'm going to go with it.

Comment: Also keep in mind that you are writing code for programmers to read.  Even if this relationship holds, it is not commonly known, and will be hard for future developers to understand.   Hashtables are fast at looking up keys -- constant time in fact -- so the savings from using the two enumerators isn't all that great unless this is a very hot piece of code, compared to the confusion for future code changes.

Comment: I actually found the first one easier to read.  It's like, "Okay, I'm grabbing all the keys and values from this table, and now I'm iterating over them.  Simple."  So I guess it's just personal preference.